# How to set application time in Java?

Tags: java

In my Java application, I use several libraries which invoke `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Instant.now()`. These functions provide the current timestamp.
I would like to set the time of the application to something different than the real time.
E.g. *1 Jan 2023 16:00*.

This will be set once at the start. During the course of execution, I want all current timestamp invocations to believe that the application has started at that time and will show timestamps accordingly, regardless of the real system time.
I would like to do this without changing the time of the computer and without affectiing other applications running on the computer.
Is this possible?

Comment: You can create a custom `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` and get the corresponding `Instant` from it without having to rely on the current date or time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *create* your own timestamp and get its epoch milli values, you could create an `OffsetDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime`) from your desired value, convert it to an `Instant` and receive the moment in time represented by epoch millis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a custom date and time in UTC
    OffsetDateTime customOdt = OffsetDateTime.of(
                2023, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC
            );
    // print it
    System.out.println(customOdt);
    // then print the underlying Instant
    System.out.println(customOdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
}
```

Output:

```
2023-01-01T16:00Z
1672588800000
```

Comment: This would mean all the libraries and third part code that I am using will have to be modified to use the OffsetDateTime. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Then maybe manipulate `Instant.now()` with a `Clock`, follow the link under your question…

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use a `Clock` to provide the current instant.  A dependency injection framework would be the best way to achieve this.  This allows you to pass in either a system clock, a clock in an alternate time zone, a clock with an offset or a clock that always returns a fixed time.

```
function doSomethingWithTime(LocalDateTime time, Clock clock) {
    assert time.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now(clock));
}
```